# Sharing a common table with unique values in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been trying to get my head around how I can create a common tag asset library with hibernate, but I can't get it to work.

I want it to look behave something like this:

[image: Unique tag library]

I want Subscription and Notification to share the same unique tag library.

I have tried with a `@ManyToMany` annotation. But I don't think that's the way to do it. In my best case scenario I want Hibernate to automatically see if a tag is already present, and then just use that id. But I'm also okay with first creating tags and then linking them. How is the best way to go about this with Hibernate?

Here's my current code:

**Subscription.class**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Subscription {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "subscription_id")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "subscription_tag",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
  private List<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<>();

  private String subscriberString;

}
```

**Tags.class**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "notification_tags",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "tag")
)
public class Tags {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "tag_id")
  private Long id;

  private String tag;

}
```

**Notification.class**

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Notification")
@Table(name = "notification")
@TypeDef(
    name = "jsonb-node",
    typeClass = JsonNodeStringType.class
)
public class Notification extends NotificationBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "notification_id")
    private Long id;

    // This is when the object was created
    private Date updatedTime = new Date();

    private Date timestamp;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "notification_tag",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    private List<Tags> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    @Type(type = "jsonb-node")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(4000)")
    private JsonNode customJson;

}
```

Comment: I've you read this one ? https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: That was a good read. My problem now is that I get a circular reference. I can solve this by using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`, but I also want to find subscriptions by tags

Comment: So, I figured it out. I just search `Subscriptions` for subscriptions with `Tag`. I'll try to submit an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some relations wrong. You should only have one Class own the relation, but the other class should reference back to that relation.

I also used `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to avoid circular referencing when Serializing to json.

When I want to search for all Subscriptions with a **tag** I did not need to search for the tag that is in all Subscriptions, but the other way around, all Subscriptions with a certain tag. See my code below.

**SubscriptionRepository.class** (to find all Subscription with a certain tag)

```
public interface SubscriptionRepository extends CrudRepository<Subscription, Long>{

    List<Subscription> findAllByTag(Tag tag);

}
```

**Subscription.class**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Subscription {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "subscription_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "subscription_tag",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "subscription_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    private Set<Tags> tags = new HashSet<>();

    private String subscriberString;

}
```

**Tag.class**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "notification_tags",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "tag")
)
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "tag_id")
    private Long id;

    private String tag;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Subscription> subscriptions = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Notification> notifications = new HashSet<>();

    public Tag() {
    }

    @Builder
    public Tag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        Tag tag1 = (Tag) o;
        return Objects.equals(tag, tag1.tag);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), tag);
    }
}
```

**Notification.class**

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Notification")
@Table(name = "notification")
@TypeDef(
    name = "jsonb-node",
    typeClass = JsonNodeStringType.class
)
public class Notification extends NotificationBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "notification_id")
    private Long id;

    // This is when the object was created
    private Date updatedTime = new Date();

    private Date timestamp;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "notification_tag",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id") })
    private Set<Tags> tags = new HashSet<>();

    @Type(type = "jsonb-node")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(4000)")
    private JsonNode customJson;

}
```